# How to fix Can't download Android Plugin component: layoutlib-resources: Check logs for details Error Message (Using IntelliJ IDE Community edition)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to build Android App using IntelliJ IDE. Design mode of activity_main.xml isn't working, Error message says Android plugin is missing. Please let me know how to fix this and proceed

As a initial step modified d8.jar & d8.bat to dx.jar & dx.bat [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OClem.png)

Comment: Seems you Android SDK directory has broken structure. Re-install the Android SK and sect the path to it in the IDE: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/setup-sdk